# returning a multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

```
string THIRDSTEP::DispSched(string movie)
{
    string data[6][7];
    ifstream file("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\MP 116\\sched1.csv");

    for (int row = 0; row < 7; row++)
    {
        string line;
        getline(file, line);
        if (!file.good())
        break;

        stringstream iss(line);

        for (int col = 0; col < 6; col++)
        {
            string val;
            getline(iss, val, ',');
            if (!iss.good())
                break;

            stringstream converter(val);
            converter >> data[row][col];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code should return a multi-dimensional array. but I don't know how. any ideas? I think pointers should be used, but how?

Comment: Your problem was answered here before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720707/how-to-return-two-dimensional-char-array-c

Comment: try making the return type `string*` instead of `string`. Also, what is it that you are returning? I don't see any returns in your code except for the `return 0`

Comment: string* will not work

Comment: @spiritwolfform why will it not work?

Comment: 0 is not a multidimensional array...

Comment: I dont know what to put so I placed 0, temporarily @twalberg

Comment: use boost::multi_array. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

Comment: Don't use arrays, use vectors. Unless you're an expert - in which case you won't use raw arrays anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a reference or pointer to `data` (i.e. `return &data`).

However, `data` will go out of scope as soon as your function returns, so this alone would be useless. What you need to do is either **pass in** a string array to the function and let it edit that, or explicitly control the lifetime of your data by using `new` and `delete`.

I'd say creating the data outside of the function and passing in a reference to it would be best in this case.

**Example with minimal changes**

```
void THIRDSTEP::DispSched(string movie, string (&output)[6][7])
{
    ifstream file("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\MP 116\\sched1.csv");

    for (int row = 0; row < 6; row++)
    {
        string line;
        getline(file, line);
        if (!file.good())
        break;

        stringstream iss(line);

        for (int col = 0; col < 7; col++)
        {
            string val;
            getline(iss, val, ',');
            if (!iss.good())
                break;

            stringstream converter(val);
            converter >> output[row][col];
        }
    }
}
```

*On a side note, you want to avoid using magic numbers like 7 and 6 in your loops. Try creating an std::vector of std::vectors and using it's iterators to find the end rather than hard coding its size.*

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
struct MyStrings
{
    string s[6][7];
};

MyStrings THIRDSTEP::DispSched(string movie)
{
     MyStrings strings;
     strings.s[2][3] = movie;
     return strings;
}
```